# Java 8 - Initilize a List in one line difference between Arrays.asList and Stream.of

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8

I want to create a list of city names. And I know two ways.

```
List<String> cities = Stream.of("Paris", "London", "New York", "Tokyo").collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("Paris", "London", "New York", "Tokyo");
```

What is difference between `Stream.of(..).collect(..)` and and `Arrays.asList(..)`?

Comment: "Preferable" in term of ?

Comment: Let's say better

Comment: "*Are these two approaches the same when are compiled to Java bytecode?*" - How could they be? One constructs a `Stream`, operates on that stream and finally creates a `List`. The other takes some varargs and creates a `List`. --- "*And, if they are not the same, which one is better for use?*" - The answer is opinion-based and thus off-topic for SO.

Comment: "better" is just as bad as "preferable". Better based on what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Stream.collect()` will return a `List<>` with non-fixed size (*with the current implementation of `toList()`*)

   ```
   List<String> cities = Stream.of("Paris", "Tokyo").collect(Collectors.toList());
   cities.add("foo"); // OK
   ```

   In the case of create a basic `List` it's useless to use `Stream`, use them when you need to make operation before collecting data, like filter, map, ...

---

2. `Arrays.asList()`will return `List<>` of fixed size : [`see Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

   ```
   List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("Paris", "London", "New York", "Tokyo");
   cities.add("bar"); // NOK : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
   ```

   This can be used when you quickly need a `List` of elements, for iteration, or other simple thing but no more, then use a implementation of `List` of go back to point 1.

---

*The construction `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` would guarantee the returned list to be mutable, as for `toList` [there are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned](http://.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));%20would%20guarantee%20the%20returned%20list%20to%20be%20mutable,%20as%20for%20toList%20there%20are%20no%20guarantees%20on%20the%20type,%20mutability,%20serializability,%20or%20thread-safety%20of%20the%20List%20returned)*

Comment: It is *not specified* that the list returned by `Collectors.toList` can be modified, though doing so happens to work in current JDK releases (8 to 10).

Comment: `Stream.of("Paris", "Tokyo").collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` would guarantee the returned list to be mutable,  as for [`toList` there are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).